# What is the difference between "écrivain" and "écriveur"?

Tags: choix-de-mot

What is the difference between the words "écrivain" and "écriveur"?

"Écrivain" appears to be by far the more common word, but "écriveur" also appears in some of my dictionaries. Are they exactly the same, or is there a difference in nuance between the two?

Comment: Considering the word is obsolete I'd like to know in which dictionaries you've found it and whether they mentioned it was obsolete.

Answer (score 5):

There are two major differences, type of writer and obsolescence.

*Écrivain* (fem. *écrivaine*) designates a professional writer or someone whose main occupation consists in writing. The word is still in use.

*Écriveur* (fem. *écriveuse*) is obsolete, and is not found in modern dictionaries. It is not in the *[TLF](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/%C3%A9criveur)*,  not in the wiktionnaire,  not in *Le Petit Robert* (1994 edition),  not the *Grand Dictionnaire Encyclopédique Larousse*, not in *Le Dictionnaire Historique de La Langue Française*,  not in the *Dictionnaire Culturel en Langue Française*, I have found it only in [Le Littré](http://www.la-definition.fr/%C3%A9criveur) et le [*Dictionnaire Critique de la Langue Française*](http://portail.atilf.fr/cgi-bin/dico1look.pl?strippedhw=ecriveur) de Jean-François Féraud, both dictionaries are considered as historical monuments but entirely obsolete.
*Écriveur* was someone who liked writing or wrote a lot, without a particular reference to the quality of their writing.
 Féraud gives an example from Mme de Sévigné :

> ... ce n'est point un écriveux...

(Mme de Sévigné's spelling). It means the person she's talking about doesn't like writing and doesn't write much.

Dictionaries will usually mention three other words in relation to writers, *écrivassier*, *écrivaillon* and *écrivailleur*, all three are derogatory terms for second-class writers. They're all used but I expect *écrivaillon* is the most commonly used.

Comment: Je pense que ça peut t'intéresser : https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/45635/167500

Answer (score 3):

Easy : a *écriveur* is what is colloquially called a writer of second class. Who writes a lot of letters, who loves to write but it is not his job

Comment: I disagree with *second-class* qualification which is a derogatory term, some *écrivains* can be second class too ...

Comment: It's not degrading to me because I just want to say that they are not professional writer or they live financially speaking. They write for themselves, for their own pleasure but does not remove financial gains. For me a writer will write in order to tell a story, to convey something but the purpose is still to sell his work.

Comment: It might not be to **you** but you can't change the meaning of words as you like. If you say something is second-class you mean it is of inferior, of lesser quality.

Answer (score 2):

Beyond the different meanings, a big difference is for *écrivain* to be a common and widely used word while *écriveur* is, despite beying easily understandable, [extremely rare](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=%C3%A9crivain,%20%C3%A9criveur&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1;,%C3%A9crivain;,c0;.t1;,%C3%A9criveur;,c0).